# Angular ajax service

Tags: angularjs, ajax, service

I want a service which can share/auto sync data to 2 or more controllers like this example:

**app.js** (from example)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.factory('Data', function(){
return { FirstName: '' };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
$scope.Data = Data;
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
$scope.Data = Data;
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HEdJF/)

Furthermore I need to load the data with ajax. I tried a bit but for ajax I need the promise (so the controller dont get changed data after init) which dont worked with the shared object like the fiddle link. If possible I want a solution without events *(rootscope broadcast)*.

How can i use both techniques together? Do you guys know what I mean? :)

Comment: You may create a method in the factory that returns a promise. And then use `Data.asyncMethod(param1, param2).then(..)` in both controllers.

Comment: My controller code is like this:
`Data.getBlub().then(function(response) {
 $scope.data = response;
});`

But if the other controller change the data, the first one dont recive the new data.

Answer (score 1):

Change your service to like this:

```
myApp.factory('Data', function(){
    this.name= { FirstName: '' };
    return this;
});
```

Controllers:

```
myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
    $scope.Data = Data.name;
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
    $scope.Data = Data.name;
});
```

Comment: I am new with angular, how can I add the async promise into that structure? If I return `this `I cant return the promise. (but I need the promise to get the data into the view)

Comment: Give some time and explore, see this link, it  have everything you want: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q and try to understand

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot and now my code is:

```
angular.module("test").factory("TestFactory", ["$http", function TestFactory($http) {
    var factory = {
        data: [],
        test: 123,
        getData: function () {
            $http.get("/blub.json").success(function (result) {
                factory.data = [1,2,3];
            });
        },
        addToData: function (newData) {
            factory.data.push(newData);
        }
    };

    factory.getData();

    return factory;
}]);

angular.module("test").controller("TestControllerA", ["$scope", "TestFactory", function ($scope, TestFactory) {
    $scope.factory = TestFactory;
}]);

angular.module("test").controller("TestControllerB", ["$scope", "TestFactory", function ($scope, TestFactory) {
    $scope.factory = TestFactory;

    setInterval(function () {
        TestFactory.addToData(TestFactory.data.length + 1);
        $scope.$apply(); //refresh view/html
    }, 1000);
}]);
```

I there a "bad" part and can be performer or something?